When are "can" and "will be able to" interchangeable and when are they not?
"Can" and "Will be able to" are sometimes interchangeable but sometimes not. I am not sure how we can distinguish them.
For example,

If I study hard, I can/will be able to pass the test=> This sounds fine with either can or will be able to.

If I study hard, I can/will be able to pass the test in July=> This sounds wrong with can. It should be will be able to only.

If it stops raining, I can/will be able to hold a party in the park this weekend=>I think both are fine, but "can" sounds more like a suggestion or an offer.


How should we distinguish between them?

can can convey current ability as well as future ability, but obviously will be able to can only refer to future ability. So "I like working from home because I can sit around all day in my pyjamas"  would normally mean I'm already doing that. But "I like working from home because I will be able to sit around all day in my pyjamas" doesn't really work (we'd normally expect "I will like working from home..." for temporal consistency).

I'm not sure that "If I study hard, I can pass the test" does sound right to me - or, at any rate, it's less natural than "will be able to" or "should be able to".

"the test in July" could identify a particular test, or refer to a test you can take many times in different months but will fail in May and June. "Can" is more natural with the former sense.
